# How to load a text or csv file which is in a different parallele directory using a python script when i do not have access to absolute path

Tags: python

I have some text files in a directory (say A/b1/b2/File.txt), while my script is in another directory (say A/m1/m2/Program.py). How do I load the text file from the python script.

I am not looking to import any module, or function from other python script, but loading a non-python file(like text or csv) from some parallel location using my python script.

Comment: Is there any reason why a relative path is not working for you: `open("../../b1/b2/<textfilename>)`?

Comment: i tried relative path but it says "no such file or directory" error, also inside b2 i have multiple file so tried using os.chdir

Comment: I would stick with the solution by Super S then as determining the path from `__file__` is your safest option in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can just enter the full address:

```
File=open("C:\A\b1\b2\File.txt") #Assuming you're using windows.
```

If you don't know the full address, then you may need to import from a library.

```
from os.path import realpath
from os.path import dirname
Path=realpath(__file__)
while Path.split("\\")[-1]!="A":Path=dirname(Path)
Path+="\\b1\\b2\\File.txt"
File=open(Path)
```

Comment: yes that C:\ part in the solution that is absolute path but i dont have absolute path with me and it has to happen in a project at run time, also there will be multiple files and not just one text file(but that i can take care of). thanks

Comment: @SourabhMehta I've added an example which uses a library, as I don't know how to do this without one. If you don't know the full address, then it would have been a good idea to mention this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

just specify the path and open it.

```
file_to_open =  r'A/b1/b2/somefile.csv'  # don't forget the 'r' here to prevent backslash issues

with open(file_to_open, 'r') as file:
     df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? I would have thought that doing that would just open `"A/m1/m2/A/b1/b2/somefile.csv"`, which won't exist.

Comment: yes, that works. add the COMPLETE path and try it out - if it works, please accept my answer.